# why we use .ejb file

Tags: ejb-3.0

I was asked to read the code of an existing project.
There they have implemented stateless session bean with the file extension .ejb.
We can have java file which extends sessionbean but wats the use of keeping the file as .ejb ?
Anyone can help me out this ?
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

You use it likely because your project uses [EJBGen](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs91/medrec_tutorials/ejbgen.html), which uses .ejb as file extension for files to be treated specially (source for code generation).